# Compare if year in date is prior to today's year

Tags: excel, datetime

I have a date in the format of "4/26/2013". I want to see if that date is prior than the current year, whatever that current year may be (don't want to hardcode 2013) and count how many of the rows match that criteria. Say there are 6 rows of dates in that format:

```
=COUNTIF(C2:C7, YEAR(Today()))
```

This threw an error. I'm new to Excel, so I probably made a huge mistake! Can anyone see what is wrong with this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If C2:C7 contain dates you need to compare them to the 1st of January in the current year, e.g.

`=COUNTIF(C2:C7,"<"&DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),1,1))`

or you can use SUMPRODUCT like this

`=SUMPRODUCT((YEAR(C2:C7)<YEAR(TODAY()))*(C2:C7<>""))`

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out. My syntax was wrong. The answer to the above example was:

```
=COUNTIF(C2:C7, ">"&YEAR(TODAY()))
```

That returned the number of dates in C2 - C7 that were prior to the current year.

Comment: That check will show items that are *later than* the current year, but you asked for *prior than*, no?

Comment: This won't work if C2:C7 contains dates because it won't be comparing like values - it compares dates with a year - you need to use a date as the criterion, see my answer